# dart flutter: Run window message 'I/zygote' 'I/Choreographer'

Tags: dart, flutter

I get the following message after some time, when the app is idle, in the 'Run window':

```
I/zygote  ( 5808): Background concurrent copying GC freed 85212(1428KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 60% free, 989KB/2MB, paused 30.930ms total 85.354ms
I/Choreographer( 5808): Skipped 605 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer( 5808): Skipped 112 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

There is no crash, and the app runs fine but is this something I should be concerned about?

Comment: If you run in debug mode this shouldn't be too concerning. Only release mode is optimized for performance.

Comment: Currently running in debug mode. Are these hidden processes prevented in the release mode? I ask this because I've extended a scoped_model class with a TickerProvider. Could it be the TickerProvider is providing excessive ticks even when not called.

Comment: In debug mode the Dart VM is used and code runs JiTed. In release mode all is compiled to a binary AoT. Performance characteristics just aren't meaningful in debug mode. The output you get is only to make you aware there **might** be performance issues.

Comment: The message began appearing only after I used a TickerProvider, may be its implementation on my part lacks something. The documentation says the ticks provided are automatically enabled/disabled in the subtree when using TickerProviderStateMixin, which I just couldn't use in this situation. Tried using the TickerMode in the subtree to prevent Ticks received.

Comment: Don't know about that. Perhaps someone else ...

Comment: Thank you, may be will ask that as another question. Will also check the documentation again. Thanks